# Standard Python names are flagged as unresolved in PyCharm, but the program runs successfully

Tags: python, pycharm

Please see attached screenshots.

PyCharm says that the red underscores indicate unresolved names. Yet, the program runs successfully and produces this output: `[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25], 15`.

It seems that the names not flagged as unresolved are those defined in the script itself. The ones that are defined as errors are defined outside the script. Even `reduce` and `add` are flagged as errors when first mentioned, but are not flagged as errors when used.

[image: Screenshot of code with error markings]

[image: Configuration]

Comment: Does this happen for any new project you create, or just this one? Have you tried creating a new virtual environment and using that for a project?

Comment: That did it! I created a new project and the problem didn't re-appear. Thanks!

Comment: Please check that interpreters specified in `Run Configuration` and `File - Settings - Project Interpreter` are the same

Answer (score 0):

When your program runs without error, but PyCharm is indicating that it doesn't know some of the modules and functions you're using, odds are that PyCharm isn't looking at the same environment that your script will have access to at runtime.

There's a number of reasons why this situation can occur, but generally the best solution is one of these:

- If you typically like for your scripts to run in the global environment (the default), make sure the interpreter for the project is set to be the copy of Python you want to use. Check `File - Settings - Project Interpreter`.
- If you prefer your scripts to run in a separate environment, either shared among your PyCharm projects, or even one per project, create a new virtual environment for your project, install the modules and packages you need in it and assign it to your project.  Same location in the menus, but instead of selecting the existing environment, create a new one (note the little cog-icon next to the selection combo in the selection dialog), by selecting `Add...`.